# SendGrid Email from VB.NET to SMS email addr doesn't arrive if subject is empty

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows, sms, sendgrid

On Azure VM Windows Server 2012, my VB.NET 2015 windows app uses SendGrid to send email.  But if subject is empty it doesn't send.  I'm sending out text messages to a mobile phone, so subject is not necessary.

If I set subject to " " it works.  But since SMS is limited to 160 chars, I don't want to waste even a space.

Comment: if the subject line supports rich text, you could send in an empty `<p></p>` or something simple like that to have some sort of data in there. Then have any user input go inside the brackets. Not really answering "why" that happens but could work.

Comment: It depends on the carrier itself, something you have no control over I am afraid. Messages are sent to the short message service center that's maintained by that carrier. Depending on setup it may require users to include a subject field no matter if it's sms or mms. If this is in place the actually message can be thrown out and you would not know. From my understanding sms usually don't require subjects only mms usually do... Again this depends on carrier to carrier. ***How do I know*** simply because I've been sending sms and mms for a long time to a variety of carriers...

Comment: If you feel like reading on this check out the IETF on the URI Scheme for Global System for Mobile Communications (GSM) RFC5724 : http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5724.txt This is an Internet Standard Track document...

Comment: I would use a rest service for sending sms messages like twilio https://www.twilio.com/sms

Comment: @KenTucker seems fine but if the sms or mms doesn't conform to the carrier it won't matter at all. It simply would be lost or thrown out. Also they have mechanisms in place for this. For example if to many are coming through it can be blocked...

Comment: To add to what Codexer and Ken Tucker are saying "For example if to many are coming through it can be blocked". I would still highly recommend using a provider like Twilio to send sms and mms instead of trying to do it through/via email. Carriers are more likely to block messages sent from/to email. A provider dedicated to sms and mms is likely to have a deeper and closer relationship with carriers and will probably have better deliverability, just like a provider that specializes in sending emails, like SendGrid, has relationships with the big players to ensure better email deliverability.